# "Enforcement literal not supported in constraint" with condition on addExactlyOne() in OR-Tools

Tags: java, or-tools, constraint-programming

This is a follow-up to [Impose Constraint on CpModel only when some relation between IntVars is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962117/impose-constraint-on-cpmodel-only-when-some-relation-between-intvars-is-true), using OR-Tools in Java. Following the answer in that question and referring to [this OR-Tools page on channeling constraints](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md), the rendered model is Invalid and can't be solved.

The main code snippet causing the issue is:

```
// iterating over int t,j; workers is a List<Literal>.

//Channel constraint:
Literal timeIsAfterStepStart = model.newBoolVar("time_"+t+"after_step_"+j+"_start");

//Implement timeIsAfterStepStart == (step.start <= t)
model.addLessOrEqual(jobVariable.start, t).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart);
model.addGreaterThan(jobVariable.start, t).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart.not());
                
//including this line causes INVALID MODEL status
model.addExactlyOne(workers).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart);
```

When using `model.addExactlyOne()`, the solver returns an Invalid Model response:

```
Starting CP-SAT solver v9.3.10497
Parameters: log_search_progress: true
Setting number of workers to 4
Invalid model: Enforcement literal not supported in constraint: enforcement_literal: 24 exactly_one { literals: 0 }
```

However, if I replace that line with the dummy code

```
//This works totally fine
IntVar dummy = model.newIntVar(0, 10, "dummy"+t+""+j);
model.addEquality(dummy, 5).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart);
model.addEquality(dummy, 0).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart.not());
```

which suggests the channeling logic is fine, and that the error has something to do with addExactlyOne(). What is causing the Invalid Model error?

**Full reproducible example:**

```
import com.google.ortools.Loader;
import com.google.ortools.sat.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReproducibleInvalidModelExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loader.loadNativeLibraries();
        class Job {
            int duration;
            String name;
            Job(int duration, String name){
                this.duration = duration;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }

        class JobVariable {
            IntVar start, end;
            IntervalVar duration;
        }

        final Job[] jobs = new Job[]{new Job(4, "A"), new Job(6, "B")};
        final int timeUpperBound = 10;
        final int numJobs = 2;
        final int numWorkers = 1;

        CpModel model = new CpModel();

        //Initialize assignments array.
        Literal[][][] assignments = new Literal[numWorkers][numJobs][timeUpperBound];
        for(int w = 0; w < numWorkers; w++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numJobs; j++){
                for(int t = 0; t < timeUpperBound; t++){
                    assignments[w][j][t] = model.newBoolVar("Worker"+w+"Job"+j+"Time"+t);
                }
            }
        }

        //Initialize IntVars and IntervalVar for each job
        Map<Job, JobVariable> jobToVariable = new HashMap<>();
        for(Job job : jobs){
            JobVariable jobVar = new JobVariable();
            jobVar.start = model.newIntVar(0, timeUpperBound, "start:" + job.name);
            jobVar.end = model.newIntVar(0, timeUpperBound, "end:" + job.name);
            jobVar.duration = model.newIntervalVar(jobVar.start,
                    LinearExpr.constant(job.duration), jobVar.end, "interval:" + job.name);
            jobToVariable.put(job, jobVar);
        }


        //Each Job has One Worker at a Time, while each Job is Active:
        for(int j = 0; j < numJobs; j++){
            JobVariable jobVariable = jobToVariable.get(jobs[j]);
            for(int t = 0; t < timeUpperBound; t++){
                List<Literal> workers = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int w = 0; w < numWorkers; w++){
                    workers.add(assignments[w][j][t]);
                }

                //Channel constraint:
                Literal timeIsAfterStepStart = model.newBoolVar("time_"+t+"after_step_"+j+"_start");

                //Implement timeIsAfterStepStart == (step.start <= t)
                model.addLessOrEqual(jobVariable.start, t).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart);
                model.addGreaterThan(jobVariable.start, t).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart.not());

                //including this line causes INVALID MODEL status
                model.addExactlyOne(workers).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart);

                //This works totally fine
                IntVar dummy = model.newIntVar(0, 10, "dummy"+t+""+j);
                model.addEquality(dummy, 5).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart);
                model.addEquality(dummy, 0).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart.not());
            }
        }

        CpSolver solver = new CpSolver();
        CpSolverSolutionCallback solCallback = new CpSolverSolutionCallback();
        solver.getParameters().setLogSearchProgress(true);
        CpSolverStatus status = solver.solve(model, solCallback);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I did some digging, and noticed that `addExactlyOne()` was added in the most recent (March '22) update to OR-Tools: maybe this is a bug in the new release, that this new method doesn't yet support constraints? See [the release notes here.](https://developers.google.com/optimization/support/release_notes)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Laurent at OR-Tools for [responding on the Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/2G4Y7AArZks). Use the following:

```
LinearArgument sumLinearArgument = LinearExpr.sum(workers);
model.addEquality(sumLinearArgument, 1).onlyEnforceIf(timeIsAfterStepStart);
```

More generally, use something like `model.add(sum == 1).onlyEnforceIf(literal).` This can functionally replace
`model.addExactlyOne().onlyEnforceIf().`